# Printing images in Safari for windows in not as expected

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, canvas, printing

I am having some set of `canvas` drawn with some contents in my `webpages` and I need to `print` those `canvas`.
I used the below code snippet to print with reference to this [source](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Print-DIV-content-without-opening-new-popup-window-using-JavaScript.aspx)

```
var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
frame1.name = "frame1";
frame1.style.position = "absolute";
frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
document.body.appendChild(frame1);
var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
frameDoc.document.open();
frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
frameDoc.document.write('</head><body><center>');
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('pagecanvas_' + i);
    frameDoc.document.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" style="border:1px solid;width:"'+ _pageWidth +'"px;height:"' + _pageHeight + '"px;margin:0px"><br />');
}

frameDoc.document.write('</center></body></html>');
frameDoc.document.close();
setTimeout(function () {
    window.frames["frame1"].focus();
    window.frames["frame1"].print();
    document.body.removeChild(frame1);
 }, 500);
```

I need each `canvas` to be printed in each paper, but the output is not as expected as the bottom part of the first page moves to the second and goes on and I got 8 pages of printed output when I have 7 canvas.

The output is same when I tried to `print` by opening new `window` also. How can I print this as a canvas must be printed in single page itself

Comment: Is Safari for windows still supported? i thought they stopped updating it a few years ago which makes it a bit worthless to develop with.

Comment: Are you talking OS windows or pop up windows in your title? If the OS, Apple stopped updating that in ~2012, seems like a strange browser to support.

Comment: @epascarello safari in windows OS.

Comment: So you support a browser that Apple does not support. Crazy. ARe you sure 500 milliseconds is enough time for any browser to load the content in the iframe? Does increasing that time help?

Comment: @epascarello: yes, I agree. but some of my clients still use it and I need to  provide support for my application for them in that browser too.